# How to build a Slide-Up Menu in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, user-interface

I'm new to Xcode development, and I'd like to develop a `slide-up menu` triggered from a `UIToolbar` in my iPhone app.

What I'm looking at is creating a subview with menu buttons, adding it to the main view, and sliding it up(visible) or down(hidden) when the `toggle` button is tapped.

How do I do this programmatically?! The **Opera app** for iPhone does this well (see the picture).

[image: opera-app]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are saying can be done by code by adding a subview to your mainview and slide it up and down to make it visible and unvisible.

1) Add a subview to far y coordinate so that initially its not visible in the view.

```
subView  =  [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,470,320,200)]]; // subView is an ivar
// Add stuffs to your subview
[self.view addSubview:subView];
```

2) Now make two IBActions showMySubview and hideMySubview and link them to the corresponding buttons or you can do some toggling with one button by checking its label.text.

3)    In your showMySubview

```
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        subView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 200);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

4) In your hideMySubview

```
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        editPopUpView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 470, 320, 200);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

You can also do some beautify things to your subview to look some good add **QuartzCore** framework to your project and import it in your .m file and add these lines after adding your subview to your mainview the import is    **#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"**

```
[[subView layer] setCornerRadius:12.0f];
[[subView layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
[[subView layer] setBorderWidth:4.0f];
[subView layer].borderColor =   [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
```

Hope This will help you in anyways :)

**EDIT :**

Adding buttons via code to your subview :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

        UIButton *btn   =   [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn.frame       =   CGRectMake(j*60,200+ 35 * i ,50 , 30);
        //[btn setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        btn.tag =   (j + 1) + (3 * i);
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(subViewButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted   =   YES;
        [subView addSubview:btn]; // its the subview we added to our main view add this after initializing the subview

    }
}
```

Now a function to catch the clicks of all the buttons

```
-(IBAction)subViewButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    switch ([sender tag]) {
    case 1:
    {
        // Do your stuff here

         NSLog(@"the tag of sender is %i",[sender tag]);

        break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
        // Do your stuff here

         NSLog(@"the tag of sender is %i",[sender tag]);

        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        // Do your stuff here

         NSLog(@"the tag of sender is %i",[sender tag]);

        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        // Do your stuff here

         NSLog(@"the tag of sender is %i",[sender tag]);

        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        // Do your stuff here

         NSLog(@"the tag of sender is %i",[sender tag]);

        break;
    }

    case 6:
    {
        // Do your stuff here

         NSLog(@"the tag of sender is %i",[sender tag]);

        break;
    }
    case 7:
    {
        // Do your stuff here

         NSLog(@"the tag of sender is %i",[sender tag]);

        break;
    }
    case 8:
    {
        // Do your stuff here

         NSLog(@"the tag of sender is %i",[sender tag]);

        break;
    }

    case 9:
    {
        // Do your stuff here

         NSLog(@"the tag of sender is %i",[sender tag]);

        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}

}
```

There may be many easy ways out there but hope this will get you a start :)

Comment: Hi Naveen, thanks a lot! This helped complete the 1st half of my task!
I'd now like to achieve that grid-like layout in the menu view, like in my attached file.
Can I use a UICollectionView with UICollectionViewCells to do that? I tried it but I'm having trouble initialising the view and its cells.

Comment: @VinodVishwanath The easy way is to add the custom buttons in that manner and give them backgroundimage

Comment: Add the buttons programtically to the subview.

Comment: @VinodVishwanath Edited my answer according to your attached image

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got most of it working, but the buttons don't render on the screen. I even tried giving the button a background color and a border, but they're just not visible! (I put the for-loops to create the buttons after the subView object is initialised. Still no go.)

Comment: I got the buttons to work - I had missed the normal.png background image. I still had to alter the for-loop a little, but it worked!
Thanks a lot for all your help! :)

Comment: @VinodVishwanath If my answer helped you in what you were seeking then you can accept it :)